# Evolution in the interpretation of the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, history, dirac-equation

As I understand, Dirac equation was first interpreted as a wave equation following the ideas of non relativistic quantum mechanics, but this lead to different problems.

The equation was then reinterpreted as a field equation and it is now a crucial part of quantum field theory.

My question is: could you provide me a reference (paper, book) that explains this evolution, including the different historical steps, etc. ?

I have a good knowledge of QM and I studying field theories, but I would like to have a clearer view on this historical evolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the details of the physics involved in the two ways of interpreting the Dirac wave equation I recommend chapters XI and XII of Dirac's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics" 4th edition, and chapters XX and XXI of Messiah's "Quantum Mechanics", vol. II. For the more historical details I recommend chapters 5 and 6 of Crease and Mann's "The Second Creation", chapters 13 and 15 of Pais' "Inward Bound" and the first chapter of Schweber's "QED And The Men Who Made It".

Answer (score 5):

I think that the first volume of the series "The Quantum Theory of Fields", by Steven Weinberg, is a good text to understand the origin of Dirac equation, QFT, and all these kind of topics.

Maybe Weinberg's books are not the best for a first course in QFT (or in General Relativity, he has also a great book on this topic), but his great coverage and unique point of view make them very worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

@Cedric: It's true that the notion of "fields" (as we have today in QFT) is something that wasn't completely developed at that time. But i never heard that Dirac's Eq was understood as a "wave equation": he was trying to explicitly describe particles (electrons) — besides, the notion that "particles" and "waves" were connected already existed at that time, in the form of von Neumann's "transformation theory" (read: Fourier Transform + distributions). On to of that, people knew that "Matrix Mechanics" (à la Heisenberg) and "Wave Mechanics" (à la Schrödinger) were two sides of the same coin (one being particle-like and the other one being wave-like).

So, before anything else, it'd be nice to corroborate this story of yours. ;-)

In any case, let me give you a couple of references that may shed some light:

1. [An Interpretive Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5609.html);
2. [From the Rise of the Group Concept to the Stormy Onset of Group Theory in the New Quantum Mechanics (PDF, 739Kb)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122003/bonolis2004.pdf).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant "wave equation" to mean "not a field equation". I'll have a look at your references, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the origins, I think you must start the history with Sommerfeld. It is Sommerfeld who gets the fine structure levels, via an amazing cancellation of two mistakes (Bohr-Sommerfeld quantisation and lack of spin). So Dirac is sailing with a clear goal: his results must agree with Sommerfeld in some way. And of course Sommerfeld orbits are already the *relativistic* correction to Bohr orbits.

If you are more worried about the evolution towards field theory, I'd add Sakurai books to the Bjorken-Drell lot. Also Mandl.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend J.D. Bjorken, S.D. Drell, *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics*.

I think this book can provide smooth introduction into Dirac equation - the book is almost dedicated to it. At the same time I discourage starting with Quantum Field Theory before learning Dirac equation - the conceptual step may be way to difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a good introductory text for  Relativistic Quantum Mechanics is Quantum Field theory- by Itzykson and Zubor. Another text is Relativistic quantum mechanics of string fields by - Greiner and Muller

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly relevant to your question, it is helpful to compare the different editions of Dirac's *Principia*.  He revised his treatment of QED every time, and such an evolution must shed light on the evolution of the Dirac eq. from a one-particle eq. to its current status as a QFT equation.  I cannot quite recommend any of Greiner's books, although i myself consult them all the time, I have the distinct impression ..... there is a kind of vagueness about his style which contrasts badly with the styles of the other texts that the posters here have recommended. I fear that that is a symptom of something.